# Manjaro Leading >>> symbol on terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, manjaro

This might be a dumb question, but I was not using linux for some time (something like a year), yesterday I installed Manjaro 20.0.3 Lysia, when I opened my terminal I was surprised by a whole different thing that I wasn't used to see. I install my Terminator as usual and there it was the same strange thing, did my google and found out that manjaro now uses something called ZSH as default bash, my question is, what is the difference? May I go back to the old one? And if not, why there is a ">>>" before my caret? I didn't find much about this ZSH thing [image: What the hell is going on?]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, zsh is not "a bash", it is a shell. Personally I prefer zsh to bash, mainly due to its better autocompletion and other configuration options. If you want to switch to bash, look into the `chsh` command.

The `>>>` that you see is part of the prompt that your zsh configuration has specified. You can change this by editing the `PS1` variable in `~/.zshrc` ( you can do the same for bash by editing `~/.bashrc`).

If you want to learn more about the features of zsh, the Arch wiki has a very nice page about it. Zsh is a very popular shell, there's surely an abundance of documentation about it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know the same and no one seems to care or know. So I decoded the quite unfamiliar prompt command myself.

My prompt has this:

```
>%{$fg[cyan]%}>%B%(?.%{$fg[cyan]%}.%{$fg[red]%})>%{$reset_color%}%b
```

Based on this:

The first > is just an uncolored static symbol.

The second > is also a static symbol colored in cyan

Only the third > has some functionality:

If "?" which contains the last return code of any command in your session is 0 (no error) then it is colored in bold cyan else it is colored in bold red.